# bash trap of TERM - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: bash, signals, bash-trap

Given this hack.c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
 int i=0;
 for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
   printf("%d\n", i);
   sleep(5);
 }
}
```

and this hack.sh bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
./hack
```

If I run hack.sh, two processes get created - one for bash, one for the C task.  If a TERM signal gets sent to the bash process, the C process is unharmed.

Now, suppose the original bash was launched from a Java program using Runtime.exec(), so the only control I have over it is Process.destroy() (which sends TERM to the bash process)?  Suppose I **want** the C process to die along with the bash that launched it?

I've been trying things like this in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "kill -TERM -$$; exit" TERM
./hack
```

i.e. a trap clause that catches the TERM signal and rebroadcasts it to the whole process group.  This doesn't work for me - a bash process with that trap clause in it **ignores** TERM signals.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The man page of bash says: If  bash is  waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes.

Comment: Have you tried using `exec` instead of keeping the shell process alive?

Comment: You're right, tangens.  My only excuse is that text is in the SIGNALS section, way above the trap documentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You might try something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
./hack &
pid=$!
trap "kill $pid" TERM
wait $pid
```

It might be simpler (and equivalent) to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
./hack &
trap "kill $!" TERM
wait
```

The double-quotes on the trap should make word expansion happen when the trap is defined, so a changing value of $! shouldn't have an impact; but I like the first version better.

Comment: This works, even though you might think it doesn't because of what tangens said in the comments on the question. BUT the complete paragraph, qouted partially by tangens, says:

Comment: If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes. When bash is waiting for an asynchronous command via the wait builtin, the reception of a signal for which a trap has been set will cause the wait builtin to return immediately with an exit status greater than 128, immediately after which the trap is executed.

Comment: Also want to add that you can kill the whole process group (the process itself and it's children) by doing: kill -TERM -$$