# Ruby: bundler exec not behaving as expected when getting signals

Tags: ruby, bundler, supervisord

I am trying to setup [Kibana](http://kibana.org) with [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org) using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com). Installing the Kibana dependencies with Bundler was no problems at all. I tried running `bundle exec ruby kibana.rb` and it worked. I also tried killing it with Ctrl-C while watching the processes that spawn in htop, and it worked.

However, when killing bundler using supervisord (or signals like SIGINT or SIGTERM for that matter) the two children spawned by it survives. So, if restarting the kibana job in supervisord, the restart will fail as the ports the restarted job will try to allocate are already in use.

From what I can find, bundler exec shouldn't fork and from what I can tell, it doesn't. It just doesn't behave as I expect when it gets signals.

What can I do? Switching from bundler could be a solution, but it is not desirable.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I wrote the little run_kibana bash helper below (found at another [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526746/bash-trap-of-term-what-am-i-doing-wrong)):

```
function kill_kibana() {
  echo "Trapped termination of Kibana subprocessess"
  pkill -TERM -P $1
}

bundle exec ruby kibana.rb &
pid=$!
trap "kill_kibana $pid" SIGINT SIGTERM SIGKILL SIGQUIT
wait $pid
```

And it works like a charm. Might be reasonable to extend it to send the actual signal that was trapped in the kill_kibana() function.